# How do I call method using interface pointer which is part of its concrete class and not part of interface

Tags: c++, oop

I  have an interface `Test_I`, which is implemented by many classes like `myTest1`,`myTest2`. I have new requirement of a writing a new class `myTest3` which has to be subclass of interface `Test_I`. Along with existing methods `myTest3` has some other new methods like `mySomeOtherTestFunction` which has no relation with parent interface `Test_I`. I must call all methods of concrete classes using interface pointer only and this can not be changed. How can I solve this problem without adding this method into parent interface.

```
class Test_I
{
public :
    virtual void myTestFunction1() = 0;

    virtual void myTestFunction2() = 0;
};


class myTest1 : public Test_I
{

public : 

    virtual void myTestFunction1()
    {
        cout<<"in myTest1::mytestFunction1"<<endl;
    }

    virtual void myTestFunction2()
    {
        cout<<"in myTest1::mytestFunction2"<<endl;
    }

};


class myTest2 : public Test_I
{

public : 

    virtual void myTestFunction1()
    {
        cout<<"in myTest2::myTestFunction1"<<endl;
    }

    virtual void myTestFunction2()
    {
        cout<<"in myTest2::myTestFunction2"<<endl;
    }
};


class myTest3 : public Test_I
{
public : 
    virtual void myTestFunction1()
    {
        cout<<"in myTest3::myTestFunction1"<<endl;
    }

    virtual void myTestFunction2()
    {
        cout<<"in myTest3::myTestFunction2"<<endl;
    }

    //I need one more method here, which is specific to myTest3 class and not related to interface Test_I
    virtual void mySomeOtherTestFunction()
    {
        cout<<"in myTest3::mySomeOtherTestFunction"<<endl;
    }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    myTest1 t1;
    myTest2 t2;
    myTest3 t3;

    Test_I *pTest = &t1;    
    pTest->myTestFunction1();
    pTest->myTestFunction2();

    pTest = &t2;
    pTest->myTestFunction1();
    pTest->myTestFunction2();

    pTest = &t3;
    pTest->myTestFunction1();
    pTest->myTestFunction2();
    pTest->mySomeOtherTestFunction(); //This will fail with error : 'mySomeOtherTestFunction' : is not a member of 'Test_I'

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot. Either don't call the method or add it to the interface or derive a new interface from the parent interface, add the method there, then call through the new pointer.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` to the derived class?

Comment: You need to *downcast* the pointer to the correct type. See e.g. [here](https://www.tutorialcup.com/cplusplus/upcasting-downcasting.htm) for more information about down and upcasting. You might also want to think about the requirements of your application, and if the design could be changed to incorporate this in a way that you don't have to downcast.

Comment: Call the new function as part of `myTestFunction1` or `myTestFunction2`?

Comment: On another note, if a function is marked as `virtual` in a base-class, it's "virtualness" will exist in the inheriting child-classes as well. You don't have to write `virtual` again in the child-classes. But I do recommend that you add the `override` special identifier to explicitly say you're overriding the function. So in your child classed do e.g. `void myTestFunction2() override { ... }`

Comment: Why can't you `t3.mySomeOtherTestFunction();` ? Where does the requirement "I must call all methods of concrete classes using interface pointer only and this can not be changed." come from

Comment: @Caleth : We can not call `t3.mySomeOtherTestFunction()` because by existing design we have to assign this `t3` to parent interface pointer. Considering existing design of my application, all methods of concrete subclasess of interface `Test_I` are called using pointer of `Test_I` only.

Comment: Either `mySomeOtherTestFunction` belongs in `Test_I`, or someone with a `Test_I` has no business wanting to call `mySomeOtherTestFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to downcast the pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class Test_I
{
public :
    virtual void myTestFunction1() = 0;

    virtual void myTestFunction2() = 0;
};


class myTest1 : public Test_I
{

public : 

    void myTestFunction1() override
    {
        cout<<"in myTest1::mytestFunction1\n";
    }

    void myTestFunction2() override
    {
        cout<<"in myTest1::mytestFunction2\n";
    }

};


class myTest2 : public Test_I
{

public : 

    void myTestFunction1() override
    {
        cout<<"in myTest2::myTestFunction1\n";
    }

    void myTestFunction2() override
    {
        cout<<"in myTest2::myTestFunction2\n";
    }
};


class myTest3 : public Test_I
{
public : 
    void myTestFunction1() override
    {
        cout<<"in myTest3::myTestFunction1\n";
    }

    void myTestFunction2() override
    {
        cout<<"in myTest3::myTestFunction2\n";
    }

    virtual void mySomeOtherTestFunction()
    {
        cout<<"in myTest3::mySomeOtherTestFunction\n";
    }
};


int main()
{

    myTest1 t1;
    myTest2 t2;
    myTest3 t3;

    Test_I *pTest = &t1;    
    pTest->myTestFunction1();
    pTest->myTestFunction2();

    pTest = &t2;
    pTest->myTestFunction1();
    pTest->myTestFunction2();

    pTest = &t3;
    pTest->myTestFunction1();
    pTest->myTestFunction2();

    // if cast fails, returns nullptr
    myTest3 *newPTest = dynamic_cast<myTest3 *>(pTest);
    if (newPTest != nullptr) {
        newPTest->mySomeOtherTestFunction();
    }

    // cast without check, undefined behavior if Test_I is not a base class of myTest3
    static_cast<myTest3 *>(pTest)->mySomeOtherTestFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

Use `dynamic_cast` if you want to use runtime type information (RTTI) to check if the cast is possible or `static_cast` if you are sure that this cast is possible.

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  Type information check before cast will be good.